# Fitting the Poisson distribution to binary data

Tags: poisson-distribution, binary-data, fitting

I'm studying several time series. The variables of interests are dummy variables which take value 1 when a certain event happened, 0 otherwise. I want to find the best distribution to describe these data. I'm using the function `fitdistr()` of R, which allows me to use as discrete distributions the Poisson and the negative binomial. I've found using a chi-square test that the Poisson describe really well these data (p-values all over 0.90, so I do not reject the hypothesis that the data are distributed following a Poisson).

My question is: can a Poisson distribution be considered a good model to describe binary data? The hypothesis testing suggests that it is, I want to know if there are theoretical drawbacks or statistical errors in such fitting. Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

If you know the only allowed values are 0 and 1, really the only sensible approach is to use the [Bernoulli distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_distribution) (equivalent to a binomial distribution with $N=1$). The Poisson does converge to Bernoulli as the mean approaches 0, but if the mean value of the sample is greater than a small value (say 0.1), the Poisson will predict values >1 that can't occur in your data. For example for a Poisson with mean=0.1, $P(0)=0.905; P(1)=0.0905; P(2)=0.00452; P(3)=0.000151$ etc., while the Bernoulli would have $P(0)=0.9; P(1)=0.1$.

Comment: Indeed there are series with very small mean values (0.0042, 0.02) where the fitting of the poisson is perfect (P-value equal to 1). I have also cases as you pointed out in your example where the poisson gives probability until 4. I have two questions: 1) my series has 215 observations it makes sense fitting a bernoulli where the number of trials is just 1? 2) a binomial would makes sense? 3) the observation may have a sort of dependence, is that a problem? 4) is so conceptually wrong fitting a poisson even if the fitting is very good? Thank you.