# Piece-wise proportional hazards model as equivalent Poisson model

Tags: survival, poisson-distribution, cox-model, poisson-regression

A proportional hazards model $\lambda_i(t|x_i) = \lambda_0(t)\exp\{x_i^T \beta\}$ can be approximated using a piece-wise constant hazard, where the duration is partitioned into intervals and the baseline hazard is constant within each interval. In [these](https://grodri.github.io/glms/notes/c7s4) notes, for example, it is shown that the death indicators $d_{ij}$ for individual $i$ and interval $j$, can be modeled as independent Poisson observations with means $\mu_{ij} = t_{ij} \lambda_{ij}$, with obvious notations.

While I can follow the proof,  this still seems wrong to me, as a Poisson distribution places probability mass on values > 1, and yet $d_{ij}$ can only be 0 or 1. Intuitively, how can you model a random variable that only takes values 0 and 1 with a Poisson distribution? I understand that for small means, the Poisson [does converge](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/394177/103007) to a Bernoulli distribution, but this approximation does not appear anywhere in the proof, and there are cases where the rate of death may be quite high.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It doesn't have a Poisson distribution, only a Poisson *likelihood*.  That is, for any observed values $y$ of $Y$ the likelihood ratios $P(Y=y;\theta_1)/P(Y=y;\theta_0)$ are the same as they would be for a Poisson distribution (which is all you need for estimation and other parameter inference). The probabilities of values of $Y$ that you don't observe don't enter into the likelihood ratios, so they need not match.

The reason you have a Poisson likelihood is that you can model the data as produced by a stopped non-homogeneous Poisson process. The process for any individual stops when that individual first dies (or when they are censored). This sort of early stopping alters the sampling distribution of the data but doesn't alter the likelihood ratios.

A simpler example is binomial vs negative binomial: the likelihood ratios for a given set of data are the same even though the sampling distributions over sets of data are different.  Here we have 5 successes and 2 failures in 7 seven trials, as binomial and negative binomial

```
> dbinom(5,7,.5)/dbinom(5,7,.3)
[1] 6.561266
> dnbinom(2,5,.5)/dnbinom(2,5,.3)
[1] 6.561266
```

Comment: This is the critical distinction I was missing: the likelihood is identical, not the distribution. I was also wondering why I couldn't use logistic regression (ie a GLM w/ Bernoulli distribution) to fit the death indicators $d_{ij}$, instead of a Poisson. I presume this is because the likelihoods do not match, and hence the coefficients $\beta$ I would obtain would not exactly correspond to those from the Cox model.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. There are also problems when you put very large numbers of nuisance parameters into a logistic regression.  *Conditional* logistic regression at each time point *is* the same as the Cox partial likelihood, but that conditions out all the time-specific nuisance parameters and conditions on the total number of events at each time point.

Comment: This may be a separate question, but do you have a quick explanation or other sources that explain why a Poisson regression is less sensitive to large numbers of nuisance parameters than a logistic regression?

Comment: I don't think there's a simple heuristic explanation, though it has something to do with the fact that the log link can be passed through an expectation.  The paper showing how logistic regression breaks is: https://doi.org/10.1093/biomet/68.1.73

Answer (score 4):

One way to think about this is that, within each time interval $j$, you are modeling the Poisson parameter $\mu_{ij}$ based on the time $t_{ij}$ to the *first* event within interval $j$ for individual $i$, where interval $j$ starts at time $\tau_{j-1}$ and ends at $\tau_j$.

Similarly to how individuals with censored event times don't contribute information beyond the last follow-up time, individual $i$ provides no information after the observed event time $(\tau_{j-1}+t_{ij})$--even if more than one event might be possible in principle. Put slightly differently, the derivation on that page shows that the likelihood of the *data you have* is equivalent to that of a Poisson model, except for a parameter-independent constant.

The extension of this approach to multiple independent individuals having the same baseline hazard then leads to a Poisson model for the total number of deaths during a shared time interval.